# ANOVA two-way with interaction missing in R

Tags: r, interaction, anova

I have a data-set where my response variable is clutch size (TCL), and two predictors that are factors: location (TYPE2) and year (AN). I did a two-way ANOVA analysis with interaction. However, in my results I am not able to see results for the interaction. The data looks like this (an example):

```
TCL
8
6
5
3
2
3
3
3
NA
4

LOC
N
S
S
N
N
N
N
S
N
N

AN
2000
2005
2005
2010
2010
2000
2010
2008
2000
2000
```

Is it because AN is independent from LOC? (i.e. if AN=2000 belongs to LOC=N, this means it is never in LOC=S). Every AN can be only in one category, either N or S.

This is my model and my result:

```
INIcrp <- aov(INI ~ TYPE2 * AN,data=todos)
summary(INIcrp)

#              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
#TYPE2          1   3437    3437   380.9 <2e-16 *** 
#AN            14  29713    2122   235.2 <2e-16 ***

#Residuals   5168  46628       9
```

Comment: Have you tried `anova(lm(INI ~ TYPE2 * AN,data=todos))`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with the example data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the interaction term is missing, but there are ways to add it in explicitly, such as :

```
aov(INI ~ TYPE2 * AN + I(TYPE2*AN),data=todos)
```

or

```
todos$TYPE2_AN <- with(todos,TYPE2*AN)
aov(INI ~ TYPE2 + AN + TYPE2_AN,data=todos)
```

Comment: Sorry I am struggling to understand what went wrong here "it was because years were different". By years you mean the AN column? And in what way were they different which caused the interaction to be missing from your results?

Comment: I came here because I was having a similar problem with interaction terms not appearing in a nested model, and wanted to point out for anyone else who comes through to double check the output of using I(term1:term2). I thought the model had ran initially because I(term1:term2) appeared in the output, but results were just the same as if I had only tested term1. I ended up having a different issue causing the interaction to not be included, but just wanted to remind anyone who came here to double check the output of anything where you used I().